Close Range UAV Control Without GPS - Relative Positioning
We have a camera on our UAV, which can create a vector between our relative position and the target position. Let's call this $T = (x,y,z)$. We will be approximately worst case 100-200m from the target, and would like an accuracy with a radius of 1.5m. We cannot use GPS, but we can use low cost IMUs, accelerometers and what not.
What would be a solution to such a problem? I know of Kalman filters, but only from a state estimation perspective, not controls. Is this a simple control problem, and are these accuracies achievable?
